# What are prerequisites for inquiry into brahman?

Tags: advaita, brahma-sutras, vishishtadvaita, dvaita

Many schools have written commentary on Brahma Sutras.

In the commentary to first verse, each school explains their meaning of atha and the prerequisites for study of brahman.

What do major schools say about prerequisites of study of Brahman? I mean advaita, dvaita and vishistadvaita school. I just read in one Brahma sutra commentary that study of Vedas is one of the prerequisite. What does this mean study of all the Vedas and Upanishads or anything else? Does it mean that one can't study Brahma Sutra commentaries without having studied all the Vedas first?

Comment: All the schools accept Veda as supereme authority about brahman. Srimad Madvacharya explicitly says that God can only be know through the study of Vedas.. So Veda Adhyayana is Mandatory..

Answer (score 3):

Once a person asked Ramana Maharishi " How can I become qualified for SELF enquiry?" to which Ramana Maharishi said "Did you just now utter the word 'I'? Then you are qualified." Truth is your birthright. For going to a Guru we need to have Sadhna chatushtaya but not for reading/knowing/ enquiring.